# How to specify multiple server names in proxy_ssl_name in nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy

My nginx upstream has multiple servers, eg:

```html
upstream backend {
        server backend1.example.com:12345;
        server backend2.example.com:12345;
        server anotherbackend.com:12345;
   }
server {
        listen     12345;
        proxy_pass backend;
        proxy_ssl  on;
        proxy_ssl_verify on;
        proxy_ssl_name  ??
```

The proxied HTTPS server can provide certificates with any of the subject names backend1.example.com or anotherbackend.com. Is it possible to configure the proxy_ssl_name to verify certificate with any of these subject names? Or do all the backend servers have to present the same certificate?

Comment: Lookup letscrypt and get yourself  familiar generating your own free TLS certs and experiment ... their nodejs tutorial is very explicit no guesswork ... Then you can test out your theories ... Have fun and welcome to SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have corresponding certificate for every server, you can use

```
proxy_ssl_name $proxy_host;
```

Or can create one certificate with all [Subjec Alt Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) inside and distribute it to all backends